# How I can use printf or disp in MATLAB to print some special format of my data set?

Tags: matlab, printf

I have a data set with 5 columns and 668 rows. I need to use these data in ampl and I need a special format of it as the following :

```
1 3 4 5 7
5 4 3 2 1
4 5 6 4 3
4 5 3 4 2
[*,*,1]: 1 2 3 4:=
4 3 2 1 5
4 5 6 7 4
3 4 5 6 7 
3 4 2 3 1
[*,*,2]: 1 2 3 4:=
4 5 6 2
4 3 2 1
4 5 3 2 
1 2 7 1
[*,*,3]: 1 2 3 4:=
 .
 .
 .
```

In other words, I have to print 4 rows then `[*,*, i]: 1 2 3 4:=` again 4 rows and that statement and so on. It should be done by a simple for loop but I don't know how to do that since I don't work with MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a string with `disp` combined with a `for` loop.
`num2str` is used to convert number to string.

For example with a matrix containing 100 lines.

```
D = rand(100,4);
for i = 1 : 4 : size( D,1 )
    disp( D( i : i + 3,: ) )
    disp(['[*,*,' num2str((i + 3)/4) ']: 1 2 3 4:='])
end
```

Comment: how about printing 4 rows then this?

Comment: I have to import my data lets call it D, then print 4 rows of it and then what you wrote abve again 4 rows and that again and so on...

Comment: thank you so much, I just get the head of variables's name in each print is there any way to remove it?